# Flutter: Convert Dropdown button to Listview.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, dropdown

I have got a Dropdown Button that shows app languages when pressed, and when anyone is selected the app language is changed. Now I need to convert this Dropdown Button to listview. builder so that the languages are shown as a list instead of a dropdown, but could not do that. I will appreciate it if someone can help.

This is my code:

Languages class

```
class Language {
  final int id;
  final String flag;
  final String name;
  final String languageCode;

  Language(this.id, this.flag, this.name, this.languageCode);

  static List<Language> languageList() {
    return <Language>[
      Language(1, "", "English", "en"),
      Language(2, "", "français", "fr"),
    ];
  }
}
```

Dropdown Button

```
DropdownButton<Language>(
  underline: SizedBox(),
  icon: Icon(
  Icons.language,
  color: Colors.blue,
),
onChanged: (Language language) {
  _changeLanguage(language);
},
items: Language.languageList().map<DropdownMenuItem<Language>>(
  (e) => DropdownMenuItem<Language>(
     value: e,
     child: Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
     children: <Widget>[
     Text(
     e.flag,
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
   ),
  Text(e.name)
  ],),
 ),
).toList(),
),
```

Comment: What is not working? Show your ListView.builder implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: Language.languageList().length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
Language language = Language.languageList()[index];
          return GestureDetector(
onTap:(){
_changeLanguage(language)
},
child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              e.flag,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                            ),
                            Text(e.name)
                          ],
                        )
);
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Tirth that it's not clear what exactly is not working. However, with what you have provided here is a reusable `ListView.builder` that will display your languages.

```
class LanguageList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Language> languageList;

  const LanguageList({Key key, this.languageList}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: languageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Text(languageList[index].id.toString()),
              Text(languageList[index].name),
              Text(languageList[index].flag),
              Text(languageList[index].languageCode),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then you could put this where ever you need it in your UI

```
LanguageList(languageList: Language.languageList())
```